# Sum of conditional expectations of a bounded stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, markov-process

Is there a proof for the following statement or is there a counter-example?

Let $\{X_t\}$ be a stochastic process
adapted to the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$.
Assuming $0 \leq X_t \leq 1$,
and $\sum_{t=1}^{T} X_t \leq c$ almost surely for some fixed $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
then it holds that:
\begin{align}
    \sum_{t=1}^{T} \mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_{t-1}] \leq c.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple counterexample.

Let $X_1$ be uniform on $[0,1]$ and let $X_2=1-X_1$.  Then we have bound (in fact, equality):
$$X_1 + X_2 \leq c\equiv 1$$
but:
$$E[X_2|X_1]+E[X_1] = 3/2-X_1$$
which exceeds $c\equiv 1$ on the event $\{0\leq X_1< 1/2\}$.